# How do I add a variable to the path of a push function in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a set of fields in a form that have the same subsets of fields. I want be able to add and remove multiple subsets in these sets. The fields are stored as arrays and generated with ngRepeat. I have buttons with ngClick to add to the array of these field sets. These functions would be identical except for the array name I want to add to. I want to pass a variable with ngInit on every button push to the function that adds to the array. What would be the correct way to do this?

my form:

```
<div ng-repeat="1 in Array1" ng-init="addBtn = '1'"></div>
<a ng-click="add(addBtn)" href=""></a>

<div ng-repeat="2 in Array2" ng-init="addBtn = '2'"></div>
<a ng-click="add(addBtn)" href=""></a>

<div ng-repeat="3 in Array3" ng-init="addBtn = '3'"></div>
<a ng-click="add(addBtn)" href=""></a>
```

my controller:

```
// add fieldset to form
$scope.add = function add (addBtn) {
    $scope.something.other. + addBtn + .push({
        fields: ''
    });
};
```

Comment: Try this:

`$scope.something.other[addBtn].push({
        fields: ''
    });`

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bracket notation here:

```
$scope.something.other[addBtn].push({ ... })
```

There's a discussion of the difference between dot notation and bracket notation in this question: [JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)